# Matrix with entries from $1$ to $16$, each occuring once, and determinant $40800$

Tags: matrices, determinant

In OEIS, it is claimed, that the largest possible determinant of a $4\ x \ 4$-matrix
with the entries from $1$ to $16$, each occuring once, is $40800$.

Unfortunately, the article does not mention a
concrete matrix with this determinant.

I tried to find a matrix with turbo pascal, but without success so far.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: A computer search will not be able to accomplish this, I think. We can form $16!$ matrices and each determinant requires $4!$ terms with product of four numbers in each. That makes a huge number of computations before you can finish such a search!

Comment: Actually, [OEIS A136608](http://oeis.org/A136608) has an example matrix with determinant -40800.
$$\begin{bmatrix}16 & 6 & 4 & 9\\8 & 13 & 11 & 1\\3 & 12 & 5 & 14\\7 & 2 & 15 & 10\end{bmatrix}$$
One just need to swap a pair of rows...

Comment: Good hidden, this matrix!

Comment: @String You can compute the determinant a fair bit more quickly than that - not blazingly fast, but faster enough, esp. since all the entries are integers.  You also have enough freedom with row and column swaps to put e.g. 1 in the top-left corner, leaving only 15! possibilities.  And 15! is within striking distance; not _small_, but not unfathomably huge.  I would bet that with some smart branch-and-bound techniques one could find the largest possible $5\times5$ determinant this way.

Comment: It is interesting to see the so-called *matrix-plot* in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B16%2C6%2C4%2C9%7D%2C%7B8%2C13%2C11%2C1%7D%2C%7B3%2C12%2C5%2C14%7D%2C%7B7%2C2%2C15%2C10%7D%7D). The darker the color, the bigger the entry. You can see how the matrix aims at pointing the column and row vectors towards as different directions as possible so the volumes of the $4$-boxes they span becomes as large as possible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$40800 = \det \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 15 & 11 & 5 & 4 \\
 10 & 1 & 14 & 9 \\
 7 & 8 & 3 & 16 \\
 2 & 13 & 12 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: What is the pattern here?

Comment: Thanks @achillehui, you've made it better.

Comment: I got this just by starting with the dumb matrix {{1,2,3...}} and hill climbing. Restart when you get stuck on a hill.
@String, Yes there are way too many combinations to brute force but the determinate function has so many symmetries that hill climbing works well. Proving this is the max is another story, you'd have to code in all the symmetries associated with the determinate to be sure you don't check combinations you've seen before.

Comment: I was thinking of it more as a question of maximizing the size of the two $4$-boxes spanned by the column and row vectors respectively. It appears as if there IS some kind of pattern hidden here.

Comment: So with strict permutations on 16, there are 16! possbilities. But a) exchanging rows just multiplies by (-1) there are six ways to do this. b) ditto for columns. c) And taking the transpose gives the same determinant. I may have missed other symmetries but if you are careful in your coding. You only have to check 16!/(2^13) things. Which is just over 2 billion. Not impossible.

Comment: Wow! Great answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: @String you're right the four-box maximize thing is equivalent. The Determinant *is* the volume form.

Comment: @amcalde: Yes, that made me think of placing $16,15,14,13$ in different rows and columns, then $12,11,10,9$ etc. But it did not seem very fruitful. But I am sure a pattern can be found based on that geometry ...

Comment: @String, you lost me there. $16! 2^{16}$ is 1371195958099968000 which is huge. But I don't know why that's relavent.

Comment: @amcalde: Sorry, I misread your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just brute force this with Java. I do not think your claim is correct as
det({{16, 1, 16, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 16}, {16, 16, 1, 1}, {1, 16, 16, 1}}) = 118125
 see:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%28%7B%7B16%2C+1%2C+16%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+16%7D%2C+%7B16%2C+16%2C+1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+16%2C+16%2C+1%7D%7D%29

Comment: I think you are only allowed to use each number in [1..16] once.