# Regarding the largest and the smallest values of a determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, upper-lower-bounds

Let

$$M_n := \left\{ |A| : A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}, a_{ij} \in \{ 1, 2, 3, \dots, n^2\}, a_{ij} \neq a_{kl}, \forall (i,j)\neq(k,l) \right\}$$

be the set of determinants of $n \times n$ matrices whose entries are taken from $\{ 1, 2, 3, \dots, n^2\}$ without repetition. Then what is $\max M_n$?

Some remark: the case $n=3, 4$ was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767665/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-4-times-4-determinant-composed-of-1-16) where it is stated without proof that
$$\max M_3 = 412, \ \ \ \max M_4 = 40800. $$
$\max M_n$ can also be found in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A085000), where one can find more information, which includes an upper bound proved in [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article1119.html) (which is also linked in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3767673/629362)).

Also, one may also ask what is $\min M_n$, but indeed $\min M_n = - \max M_n$, which can be seen by switching two neighboring rows.

Comment: The minimum is simply the opposite of the maximum (it is enough to swap two columns), hence it is enough to find the maximum value.

Comment: Very sensible on your part.

Comment: For $n=2$, $b=10$. $$\pmatrix{3&1\cr2&4\cr}$$

Comment: Have you tried looking up the answer into OEIS?

Comment: @Crostul, no. What exactly should I search for there?

Comment: Somewhat similar, but actually very different question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428375/the-maximum-value-of-determinant

Comment: Why was the question closed? It is unfortunate and a drawback of stackexchange.

Comment: How should I improve this?

Comment: The $n=4$ case is discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905437/matrix-with-entries-from-1-to-16-each-occuring-once-and-determinant-40800 and also at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767665/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-4-times-4-determinant-composed-of-1-16

Comment: Your question is closed since it is missing context. But after the context provided here in the comment, I doubt if the post can be easily answered.

Comment: So, Firdous, have you checked the oeis link? Does it bring you up to speed on your question?

Comment: Earth to Firdous – come in, please.